# Передача аргументов функции из функции

Tags: python

Не знаю правильно ли сформулировал вопрос, но все же...
У меня есть функция, в которой опредяется 4 переменные путем ввода пользователем,
    find(lat, lon, pod_str, city):

Где lat, lon - float.
И есть функция поиска по ним...

```
def search(lat = None, lon = None, pod_str = None, city = None):
"""You search by latitude and longitude"""
if lat and lon and pod_str is None and city is None:
    list1 = []
    for line in file_airport.readlines():
        Str_file = ''.join(line)#.title()
        List_file = Str_file.split(',')
        list1.append(List_file)
        if not line:
            break
    file_airport.seek(0)
    for item in list1:
        item.append(sqrt((float(item[11]) - float(lat))**2 + (float(item[12]) - float(lon))**2))
    list2 = sorted(list1, key = lambda x: x[-1], reverse = False)
    list_new = []
    x = 10
    for item in list2:
        while x > 0:
            x -= 1
            list_new.append(item)
            break
    config = yaml.load(open('findairport.conf'))
    outs = config['output']
    for List_file in list_new:
        for out in outs:
            out = out % dict(airportcode = str(List_file[0]).upper(), distance = List_file[-1], \
                    airportname = List_file[13],  sa = List_file[8], street = List_file[10],\
                    city = List_file[7], state = str(List_file[5]).upper(), zip = List_file[3], \
                    country = str(List_file[2]).upper(), lat = str(List_file[11]), lon = str(List_file[12]+'\n'))
            print out
    file_airport.seek(0)
elif lat is None and lon is None and pod_str or city:
    print 'kakawka'
elif lat and lon and pod_str or city:
    print 'kakawka'
```

Почему если я не ввожу lat and lon, программа не заходит в последние 2 условия?
Вот условия вызова функции find()

```
if lat and lon:
    search(str(lat),str(lon))
elif pod_str and city:
    search(pod_str, city)
elif pod_str:
    search(pod_str)
elif city:
    search(city)
elif lat and lon and pod_str and city:
    search(str(lat),str(lon), pod_str, city)
elif lat and lon and pod_str or city:
    search(str(lat),str(lon), pod_str, city)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы неправильно используете именованные параметры. Если их явно не указывать, то параметры передаются по очереди, поэтому, когда вы пишите

```
search(pod_str, city)
```

вы присваиваете параметру lat значение pod_str, а параметру lon - city. Правильно вызывать так

```
search(pod_str=pod_str, city=city)
```